# Firebase: Firebase serve = The default Firebase app already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase

So, when trying to run firebase serve, I'm prompted with the error:

> Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name:

```
at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
at new FirebaseAppError (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:123:28)
at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.initializeApp (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:68:23)
at FirebaseNamespace.initializeApp (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:442:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\fullstackTest-functions\functions\util\admin.js:3:7)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
```

!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)

I'm kinda new to firebase and totally clueless about why I'm getting this error. In my app I'm calling:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

And

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you calling both `admin.initializeApp();` and `firebase.initializeApp(config); ` ? . if so that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a second project, the error message is telling you to:

> pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name

You're not passing that second argument.  You need to give the second initialized instance a unique name:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config, "your-unique-name");
```

Please refer to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initializeapp) for more details.